# NSString match a string beginning and replace the string if matched

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Here is my NSString:

```
<meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width=2C initial=-scale=3D1.0">
```

I want if the string begins with `<meta name=3D"viewport` to replace everything between the `<` and `>` (including the `<` and `>`)

If for example I have a string this:

```
<meta test>
    <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width=2C initial=-scale=3D1.0">
<meta 2>
```

After I process it, it becomes:

```
  <meta test>
  <meta 2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

Search: `<meta name=3D"viewport[^>]*>`

Replace: `""`

Untested code:

```
NSString *string = @"<meta name=3D\"viewport\" content=3D\"width=3Ddevice-width=2C initial=-scale=3D1.0\">";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<meta name=3D\"viewport[^>]*>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```